# Issue with storing image via url as array in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Whenever I retrieve an image file from local storage system to use in react project it doesn't shows image, it works when I use image from external internet link. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
export const SliderData = [
      {
        image:
          "/Users/lobe/Documents/slider/reactslider/src/images/IMG_1314.jpg",
      },
      {
        image:
          "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501446529957-6226bd447c46?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1489&q=80",
      },
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the problem with local path use absolute path instead `<img src={window.location.origin + **yourUrl**} />`